# How to set id attribute of combo-box ITEMS in GWT (Google Web Toolkit) for Selenium

Tags: gwt, selenium, combobox

I've been looking for a clear way to set id in combobox items since GWT creates a  for each combobox items without an id attribute..

I want to set an id attribute for my Selenium Test..

How can i do that?

Hope u can give me a clear steps because I am really stuck right now..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set an `id` attribute on any widget's element, by calling

```
yourWidget.getElement().setId("yourId");
```

Comment: i can set an id in the COMBOBOX but not in the COMBOBOX-ITEMS.. how could i do that? thanks for repyling

Comment: Solved this using

setTemplate method

Ex. 

combo.setTemplate("<tpl for=\".\"><div class=x-combo-list-item id={name}>{name}</div></tpl>");